# Pyspark - From a key-list pair, retrieve only the key and the first element of the list

Tags: list, pyspark, key-value

I have a rdd of key-list pairs whereby the value for a given key is a list of elements as shown below:

```
a = [('json1', ['9', 3]), ('json2', ['5', 2])]
```

From a, I would like to end up with only the key and the first element of the list as follows:

```
b = [('json1', '9'), ('json2', '5')]
```

What operations in pyspark should I use for getting this?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You need map operation  only.

```
a = sc.parallelize([('json1', ['9', 3]), ('json2', ['5', 2])])
b=a.map(lambda x:(x[0],x[1][0]))
print(b.take(2))
```

output

```
[('json1', '9'), ('json2', '5')]
```

you can read [pyspark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) about map and other operations.